# AWS app analytics data

Tags: android, web-services, amazon-web-services, analytics

We are using Amazon Mobile Analytics to collect app usage for Android using AWS Android sdk.
Since our application is business related we are tracking some custom events. Now we want show those custom events analytics to app user on Android device. Is there any way to get our app analytics data in the form of web services so that we can show the data to our users on Android app?

I have posted the same question on AWS forum [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=559734#559734), unfortunately I have not got any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Mobile Analytics recently released the "Auto Export" feature.  This enables you to get your raw events in an S3 bucket.  From there you can easily build a web service around it or simply read the raw S3 file.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/17/introducing-amazon-mobile-analytics-auto-export/